# How can I paste data only to visible cells?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, multiple-columns

I have a worksheet ('Sheet 1 ') where I have hidden two columns. I would like to copy data from another workbook and paste it into Sheet 1 but only into the visible cells i.e. all cells in the respective rows excluding the two columns I have hidden.

I understand that there is a manual way to paste specially into visible cells only but since the amount of data to be copied is large and takes multiple rounds, I am looking for a way to automate this process. Essentially, forcing all entries pasted into the worksheet to skip the hidden columns and paste only to the visible ones.

I also have code that allows me to copy and paste from within the same worksheet but not from a different workbook.

Any pointers?

Edit: I have added some code I found online which worked for within the same worksheet here. But this prompts the user to select an input range and output range and works within that.

```
Sub CopyFilteredCells()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim n As Integer
xTitleId = "Example"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Copy Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Paste Range:", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    For Each rng2 In OutRng
        If rng2.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth > 0 Then
           If rng2.EntireColumn.Hidden Then
           Else
                n = n + 1
                rng2 = InputRng.Cells(1, n)
            End If
        End If
    Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Add the code you use to paste within the same worksheet

Comment: The code that you use that copy/pastes from within the same worksheet.  Does it have references (i.e.: `(1, 4)`, or `(A1)`) or anything like that?  [Edit] that code into your question, I think we can help you by using your existing code to explain.

Comment: I've added some code somebody else pointed me to to my original question.